# Get GMT time in Android always in European letters

Tags: android

I'm currently running to the following problem:
I'm running this command

```
TimeZone.getDefault();
```

While my phone (Galaxy S6 with Android 7.0) is configured to with system language of Arabic (`العربية` to be precise).
The output of this call is: `GMT+٠٢:٠٠` and not `GMT+02:00` as I would expect it to be.

I've noticed that this issue happens only on Samsung devices (at least from the errors that I saw in my logs).

Is there a way to make sure that the timezone which I'm getting will be in the format of `GMT+02:00` regardless of the locale of the phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution which I've found:

```
final static String am = "GMT-%02d:%02d";
final static String pm = "GMT+%02d:%02d";
final String timezone = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, offset < 0 ? am : pm, hours, minutes);
```